# Is a good design that use inner class in the class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class called `SalesOrder` (SO), that allows users to buy several items in a single order. SO has an order number.

```
class SalesOrder {
   public String orderNumber;
}
```

Each SO has many items in it, so I have created a new class `OrderItem` which has the item name and price.

```
class OrderItem {
    public String name;

    public double price;
}
```

Each SO has a order header, include user name and address. It also has a field called total price, which hold the sum of all items prices

```
class OrderHeader {
    public String username;

    public String address;

    public double totalPrice;
}
```

After that, I added two fields to SO:

```
class SalesOrder {
    ...

    public List<OrderItem> items;

    public OrderHeader header;
}
```

Because OrderItem and OrderHeader are always used with SalesOrder and the header should return all items prices, I converted them to be be inner classes of SalesOrder.

```
class SalesOrder {


    ...

    public  SalesOrder() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        this.header = new OrderHeader();
    }   

    public class OrderItem {
       ...
    }

    public class OrderHeader {
        ...

        public double getTotalPrice() {
             double total = 0.0;
             // loop SalesOrder.items
             total += items[i].price;          
             return total;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether using inner classes like this is good OOP design? If not, how should they be designed?

======= Update Some information =======

I'm very sorry that I haven't give more inforamtion.

Header and Item make they construe method private, other object can't create them without SalesOrder.

SalesOrder have a factory method

```
class SalesOrder {
    ...

    public SalesOrder parseOrder(Xml xml) {
        //init header and items from xml
        this.header = new OrderHeader(valueFromXml, valueFromXml);
    }

    public class OrderHeader {
        ....
        private OrderHeader(username, address) { ... }
    }

    public Class OrderItem {
       ...

        private OrderItem(name, price) { ... }
    }
}
```

And other object use them like this

```
Xml xml = orderXmlData;
SalesOrder order = SalesOrder.parseOrder(orderXmlData);
OrderItem item = order.item;
OrderHeader header = order.header;
```

Comment: Some helpful reading -> [When to Use Nested Classes, Local Classes, Anonymous Classes, and Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html)

Comment: Would you ever need to create `OrderItem` or `OrderHeader` without an instance of `SalesOrder`?  Would you ever want to use `OrderItem` or `OrderHeader` independently of `SalesOrder`?  If no to either, then it's probably not a bad use-case, otherwise I would seriously reconsider the design

Comment: Inner class like this can help define a relationship of child classes to a parent class and can act as a type of namespace.  From a design point of view, it's clear that your intention is, `OrderItem` and `OrderHeader` are always associated with some instance of `SalesOrder` (if this isn't your intention, then you have a design problem)

Comment: OrderItem and OrderHeader always use by SalesOrder. In Fact, other object can't create item and header instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few suggestion I would have that might improve your design. Firstly, it seems unlikely to me that the `totalPrice` should be part of the header. It seems more likely that it is derived from the order items rather than being a component of the header. Secondly, unless you want clients of the class to create order items independent of the order then there seems no need to define them as a class. Better to convert to an `interface` returned from the order. Thirdly, there's no reason why `Header` can't be interface - this allows a client to use any class they want as a header as long as it has name and address.

So my suggestion would be something like:

```
class Order {

    interface Item {
        String getName();
        double getPrice();
    }

    interface Header {
        String getName(); 
        Address getAddress();
    }

    public Order(Header header) {
        ...
    }

    public double getTotalPrice() {
        return streamItems().mapToDouble(Item::getPrice).sum();
    }

    public void addItem(String name, double price) {
        ...
    }

    public Stream<Item> streamItems() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of nested classes depends on the requirements. I do not see any need for the use of nested classes in your code. If it is a Java Beans class, then you should keep the classes separated so they can be reusable. Other than your last block of code with the nested classes, your design is perfect.